# KFImage image loaded but not displayed?

Tags: swiftui, kingfisher

I am trying to display remote images using `Kingfisher` SDK , the images are loaded but its not displayed

```
    import SwiftUI
    import Kingfisher
    
    
    struct Tab_Home: View {
        
        
        //Slider
        @State var sliderIndex:Int = 0
        //Search bar
        @State var search:String = ""
        @ObservedObject var API = REST_API()
        
        var body: some View {
            
            VStack{
                
                ZStack{
                    
                    Group{
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.1))
                                   .cornerRadius(22.5)
                        
                        HStack(spacing : 0){
                            
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width : 20 , height : 20)
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .padding(.leading , 10)
                            
                            TextFieldPro(placeholder : Text("Search").foregroundColor(.white), text: $search)
                                     .padding(.leading , 10)
                                     .padding(.trailing , 15)
                                     .frame( height : 45)
                                     .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                      
                    }.padding(.leading , 10)
                     .padding(.trailing , 10)
                     .padding(.bottom , 5)
                     .padding(.top , 15)
                    
                }.frame(height : 65)
                 .background(Color(hex: "#CC2323"))
             
                 Spacer()
                
                ScrollView{
                    
                   TabView(selection : $sliderIndex){
                        ForEach(Env.sharedInstance.settings.sliders , id : \.self){ slider in
                           SliderBite( data: slider).frame(width :UIScreen.main.bounds.width )
                        }
                      } .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                    
                    
                }
                .padding(.top , 10)
                .onAppear(){
                    API.checkin()
                }
                
            }
           
        }
    }
    
    struct Tab_Home_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            Tab_Home()
        }
    }
    
struct SliderBite: View {
 
    let data:DTO_SLIDER
    var body: some View {
      
        Group{
            if data.full_image != nil {
                KFImage(URL(string: data.full_image!)!)
                .fade(duration: 0.25)
                .onProgress { receivedSize, totalSize in  }
                .onSuccess { _ in print("Image loaded") }
                .onFailure { error in print("Load image error : \(error)") }
                .frame(width :UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height : 200)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .background(Color.black)
            }
        }.clipped()
    }
}

//Decoded from rest API

    struct DTO_SLIDER:Decodable,Hashable{
        var full_image:String?
    }
```

what did i miss there ?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a reproducible example? Your code relies on lots of code that isn't present (`API`, `SliderBite`, `TextFieldPro`, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with KFImage, which is loading as expected, but with the fact that TabView is somehow unaware that the image has been loaded and that it needs to re-render it, but it can be solved easily:

Store your urls to display in an array and then use ForEach inside the TabView - this is enough to make the images appear once they are loaded:

```
struct TabHome: View {
    
    @State var search: String = ""
    let urls = [
        "https://www.broadway.org.uk/sites/default/files/styles/banner_crop/public/2019-10/star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-banner-min.jpg?h=639d4ef1&itok=z4KZ-3Tt",
        "https://www.broadway.org.uk/sites/default/files/styles/banner_crop/public/2019-11/star-wars-quiz-banner-min.jpg?h=f75da074&itok=bFe6rBe_"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing : 15) {
            HStack(spacing : 10) {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                TextField("Search", text: $search)
                    .frame(height: 45)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22.5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                )
            .padding()
            
            ScrollView{
                TabView {
                    ForEach(urls, id: \.self) { url in
                        SliderBite(url: url)
                    }
                }   .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might also want to make your KFImage resizable:

```
struct SliderBite: View {
    
    let url: String
    
    var body: some View {
        KFImage(URL(string: url)!)
            .resizable()
            .fade(duration: 0.25)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(height : 200)
            .background(Color.black)
    }
    
}
```

[image: Loaded KFImage inside TabView]

**To address showing of images from identical url**

If you declare DTO_SLIDER like this:

```
struct DTO_SLIDER: Decodable, Identifiable {
    
    let full_image: String?
    let id = UUID()
}
```

it will ensure each one is unique even if it has identical full_image.
It also means you can use it like that:

```
ForEach(Env.sharedInstance.settings.sliders) { slider in
    //...
}
```

Comment: I believe ur solution worked , but the white paging dots are not switching when i swap between images , i should do this manually ?

Comment: Are you using two different urls as in my answer? If you are using two identical urls - they have the same identity so the dots won't work.

Comment: i've make a class for each url information with Hashable protocol. `struct DTO_SLIDER:Decodable,Hashable{
    
    var full_image:String?
    
} ` , then make the loop like u did

Comment: Can you share it? How is it made identifiable?

Comment: I've updated the question with the new modifications on the code

Comment: I've accepted ur answer , thanks for the solution , but if u manage to solve the white dots issue to auto switch on swap that would be amazing too <3

Comment: Thank you, did adding id to DTO_SLIDER not help? The dot problem is due to SwiftUI nothing able to differentiate between the two urls. Can you show me how `Env.sharedInstance.settings.sliders` is declared? Maybe that's were the problem is.

Comment: the Env.sharedInstance.settings.sliders has 2 params in each object which is url and sid , sid is uniq incremental id .. I've tried ur updated it didn't help  :( the dots still not moving